# Free-fall with linear drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

The standard first-course free-fall with linear drag situation posits a particle falling with a constant acceleration (typically due to approximation of gravity), but with a retarding force that is proportional to the velocity. The equation of motion for the particle is written as

$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-mg-\lambda v \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\textrm{or}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-mg-\lambda\frac{dy}{dt}$$

The solution for the velocity as a function of time, $v(t)=\frac{dy}{dt}$, is simply a decreasing exponential plus a constant. On the other hand, the solution for the position as a function of time, $y(t)$, is a decreasing exponential plus a linear term plus a constant, which is a bit more complicated. It's complicated in the sense that the inverse function, $t(y)$, is transcendental (involving the Lambert $W$-function), so solving for the time at which the particle is at a certain height is typically not easy (analytically).

My goal is to somehow change this problem so that, given initial conditions $v(t=0)=0$ and $y(t=0)=h$, I can solve for the velocity at the time/position when/where the particle "hits the floor" (i.e. $v(y=0)=v(t_{\textrm{hit}})$) analytically.

If we multiply the original differential equation by $v^{-1}$, we get

$$m\frac{dv}{v\,dt}=m\frac{dv}{dy}=-\frac{mg}{v}-\lambda$$

This is a nonlinear differential equation with an obvious singularity at $v=0$. I don't know how to solve this, and I don't know how to get a sensible closed-form expression for my desired quantity $v(t_{\textrm{hit}})$. I made a hand-waved plot of what the solutions would look like.

[image]

**Is it possible to find a nice closed-form solution for $v(t_{\textrm{hit}})$? If so, am I on the right track? Please give suggestions.**

Comment: The linear term has nothing to do with the problem, at all. It's just a transformation into a completely equivalent inertial system, which is physically irrelevant.

Comment: I can't see how that would simplify the problem. Maybe you could expand on it? The linear term has coefficient $-mg/\lambda$, so from what I understood, you are suggesting to make the transformation $y'=y+(mg/\lambda)t$, $t'=t$. In that inertial system, there would be no linear term, but now we would be solving for $y'(t_{\textrm{hit}})$, and that isn't necessarily equal to 0 as it is in the original inertial frame.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan: you seem to want to needlessly want to complicate things. $m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-g-\lambda\frac{dy}{dt}$ is easily solved. Form there any information you want should be deducible.

Comment: @Gert I know that that equation is easily solvable. I even stated what the solutions will behave like. What I'm saying is that to solve for the velocity of the particle when it has "hit the ground" (i.e. $y=0$) doesn't seem to be an easy task. I can't see how to get a closed-form solution for that particular quantity.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan: the equation of motion should be $m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=mg-\lambda\frac{dy}{dt}$, BTW.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan - If by "closed form solution" you mean "expressible as a finite combination of elementary functions", the answer is you can't. You already showed that the inverse function is non-elementary. End of story.

Comment: My whole point is that you won't learn anything about the physics by hitting on the linear term. If you need a numerical value for an arbitrary boosted system, calculate one, but it won't tell you anything that is physically relevant.

Comment: @CuriousOne But you aren't saying anything on the "easiness" of doing the calculation in one frame relative to another, right?

Comment: @DavidHammen I have shown that $t_{\textrm{hit}}$ is non-elementary, but I don't know if $v(t_{\textrm{hit}})$ is non-elementary as well. I was hoping it wasn't.

Comment: I am saying that if the solution is simple in one frame then you are done. You aren't going to learn anything from going into a frame in which it isn't.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's not necessarily obvious and it's probably the answer here: "Accelerating reference frames are not simplifications."

Comment: @Gert - You are missing the point of the question. Yes, $m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\lambda\frac{dy}{dt}+g$ is easily solvable for $y(t)$ given any arbitrary $t_0$, $y(t_0)$ and $\dot y(t_0)$. The question is asking how to invert that solution and solve for $t$.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan - You have a function involving the non-elementary Lambert W function as your inverse. You are not going to be able to twist that into an elementary function. See http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9.pdf. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29.

Comment: @BlackbodyBlacklight: Please read my statement, again.

Comment: @DavidHammen But can nothing act on a non-elementary function (or take it as its argument) and produce an elementary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation 
$$
m\frac{dv}{dy} = -\frac{mg}{v}- \lambda
$$
is solvable, but it doesn't lead to a closed expression v=v(y). It gives instead y=y(v), which will leave you with a simple looking, but still transcendental equation for v(y=0).

To solve, separate your variables before formal integration:
$$
\frac{v}{v + \frac{mg}{\lambda}}dv = -\frac{\lambda}{m}dy
$$
Integration obtains then
$$
v - \frac{mg}{\lambda}\ln\left( v + \frac{mg}{\lambda} \right) = -\frac{\lambda}{m}y + C
$$ 
From the initial condition $v=0$ for $y = h$ the integration constant is 
$$
C = \frac{\lambda h}{m} - \frac{mg}{\lambda}\ln\frac{mg}{\lambda}
$$ 
so the final expression becomes 
$$
y(v) = h + \frac{m^2 g}{\lambda^2}\left( \ln\left( \frac{\lambda v}{mg} + 1\right) - \frac{\lambda v}{mg} \right)
$$
Note that since $v<0$ and $\frac{\lambda |v|}{mg} < 1$, the term in $v$ on the rhs is negative as it should. For y=0 we are left with 
$$
\frac{\lambda^2 h}{m^2 g} + \frac{\lambda v_{hit}}{mg} = \ln\left( \frac{\lambda v_{hit}}{mg} + 1\right)
$$

As I said, it's still a transcendental equation, but at least it's only logarithmic.